# typo3 cache_pages table have huge size

Tags: caching, typo3

I use Typo3 version 4.5.19 - I have a huge problem with cache_pages table - for page id=1 i have hundreds of records and database size grow higher then 500 M in less then 24 hours.
On this page I have plugin tt_news installed . I also have other different TYPO3 installation with tt_news and for them I don't have this problem . I can't figure out which is the problem.
Have any thoghts what should I do?

Comment: As this relates to TYPO3 4.5, it is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have various GET params that create different cache entries for each view of the same page. If you google for "typo3 cache_pages huge" you will get quite a few results, e.g. someone had a calendar plugin and it generated a page cache copy for each view of the calendar.

There are two caching mechanisms in TYPO3 < 4.6, the newer of which is called caching framework. I'm not sure which you're running on, and how it should help, but it seems related.

Also check your cHash settings; this article might be helpful: http://www.typo3-media.com/blog/chash-caching-typo3.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your news plugin is the problem, since this would rather affect the cache_hash table.

A possible problem could be conditions in your TypoScript. If you do a condition like `[globalVar = GP:L = 1]`, note that this will create an additional cache entry in cache_pages. You can see all your conditions at once in the TypoScript object browser.